# How do I make endpoints compatible with Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I added a service reference to my project and the following warning appears in my error list...

" Custom tool warning: No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 4 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor. "

How do I create SL4 compatible endpoints? Why is my current endpoint not compatible with SL4? I'm currently trying to use a webHttpBinding but have also tried wsHttpBinding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `basicHttpBinding` or checkout [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/).